# Hot to replace the stdout the last line of the last control character via sed command?

Tags: bash, sed, regexp-replace

I wanna replace(delete) the last line of the last control character `newline` form `ls` command stdout result.
Which I had try sed command is :

```
ls | sed '$ s/[[:cntrl:]]$//'
ls | sed '$ s/[[:graph:]]$//'
ls | sed '$ s/[[:print:]]$//'
```

The result I want like this result `ls | head -c -1`

Any wrong with my sed command?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -z 's/\n$//' file
```

Answer (score 0):

sed appears to automatically add a  newline if  the current line was terminated with a newline, and I don't see how to turn that behaviour off.

You might try a different approach: capture the output of the command (the command substitution syntax strips trailing newlines); and then print it without a newline

```sh
printf '%s' "$(ls)"
```